# what is the actual difference between transformNodeToObject vs transformToDocument/transformToFragment

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, xslt, browser, cross-browser

Can someone explain me the difference between transformNodeToObject vs transformToDocument/transformToFragment.
Gone through many blogs and forums but still there is confusion between this two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has a COM based XML software package providing an XML DOM implementation and XSLT and XPath 1.0 against that DOM. It is currently available in two versions on all supported Microsoft OS with latest service packs, namely as MSXML 3.0 and MSXML 6.0 (where the main difference are the backwards compatibility of MSXML 3.0 with older versions no longer supported and the stricter security settings and the XML schema support in MSXML 6.0). Via COM automation it is possible to use MSXML with JScript in various host environments, like classic ASP, Windows Script Host and Internet Explorer. The MSXML DOM provides two methods on DOM nodes to perform an XSLT 1.0 transformation, namely `transformNode`, which returns the transformation result as a string, and `transformNodeToObject`, which writes the transformation result to an MSXML DOM node or a classic ASP Response object or an IStream implementation. Inside of IE, as long as you want to use XSLT to create HTML to be inserted into your HTML document, you usually use `transformNode` and then `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML` to insert the transformation result into the HTML document, requiring a HTML parse step, as the IE HTML DOM and the MSXML XML DOM are different implementations and you can't simply include or import or adopt an MSXML DOM node into an IE HTML DOM document.

The Gecko rendering engine in Mozilla browsers provides a different API to perform XSLT 1.0 with Javascript as in Gecko the HTML DOM builds on the XML DOM and you can create DOM nodes with XSLT that can be inserted into an HTML or XML document. So the usual way to create some nodes with XSLT 1.0 in Gecko to be inserted into an existing DOM document (usually HTML but could be SVG as well) is to use the `transformToFragment` method as that way the XSLT processor directly creates nodes owned by the HTML or XML document you want them to be inserted in, without any need to serialize to string and reparse as HTML, as done in IE.

Finally the `transformToDocument` method allows you to use Javascript and XSLT 1.0 in Mozilla to create a separate result document, similar to `transformNodeToObject` with MSXML, but of course in Mozilla the method simply returns the result document while with MSXML you need to create an empty one first and then pass it to the transformNodeToObject method.

That is my understanding of the differences in API design and implementation in Mozilla and IE/MSXML, other browsers have copied the Mozilla API but can have a different implementation as for instance Chrome integrated an existing XSLT 1.0 processor like libxslt with its own DOM implementation.